# Is flowing with RG in 1D Ising model equivalent to changing the temperature of the system

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, renormalization, ising-model, spin-models

Let us consider the easiest form of the Ising Hamiltonian:
$$ \beta H(s_i; J) = -J\sum_i^N s_i s_{i+1} $$ ($\beta = 1/k_BT$ so we already defined $J = \tilde{J}/k_BT$ with $\tilde{J}$ constant).
Dividing the lattice into 3-spin blocks and using the decimation rule (keeping the middle spin in every block and summing over the other ones), one can find the new Hamiltonian in the form:
$$ \beta H(\sigma_i;J') = -J'\sum_i^{N/3} \sigma_i\sigma_{i+1} + \frac{N}{3}\cdot\mathrm{const.} $$
where $$ J' = \mathrm{tanh}^{-1}[(\mathrm{tanh} \, J)^3].$$
Up to a constant (which cancels out when we divide by the partition function), the Hamiltonian has almost the same form as the initial one. If we now send $N/3 \rightarrow N$ (which I guess we can do without harm in the limit $N\rightarrow \infty$), maybe rescale the lattice, and forget about the constant, we recover precisely the first Hamiltonian, but with a different coupling constant.

My question: is it correct to interpret this new Hamiltonian as the same system but just in different temperature (i.e. via the formula $J' = \tilde{J}/k_BT'$ where $T'$ is the new temperature)? That is, is studying the RG flow (integrating out some deegres of freedom and doing the above rescalings) fully  equivalent to studying the effects of changing the temperature in our system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that studying RG flow is not exactly the same as studying changes in the system's temperature. If I have interpreted your question correctly, you are asking about the physical significance of the RG process. Integrating out degrees of freedom corresponds to coarse-graining your detector in some way, e.g. in the decimation process you mentioned, your initial detector had a tip that had a thickness of the order of a lattice spacing so it could resolve the directions of individual spins. Now if you decide to use a thicker tip which can only resolve a block of three spins, all the correlations or properties you measure will be governed by the coarse-grained Hamiltonian. That would mean the properties of a sample at a temperature T measured with an instrument that has a thick tip would be the same as that of a sample at T' measured with an instrument with a thinner tip. Hope this helps!